# Export unused function for linting

Tags: javascript, lint, eslint

I have the following code in a Javascript file:

```
/* exported something */

function something() {}
```

The `something` function is not used in the file because it is called from a Html form submission.

When the linter runs, `es-lint` in my case, I receive a `no-unused-vars` message.

I expected that `exported` comment would fix this, but this is not the case.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Try eliminating the space between the pragma and code:

```
/* exported something */
function something() {}
```

If this doesn't work, then you can always edit your eslint config so that the `vars` property only looks at functions in local scope:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": [2, {"vars": "local", "args": "after-used"}]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the function in global scope or function scope?

Comment: it is in function scope, I tried also in global scope but it gives me a no-unused-vars anyway

Comment: I'm guessing that even though its in function scope, its still accessible by your HTML.  Updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: the new suggestion works for global scoped functions. I'm still wondering why the exported pragma doesn't work as expected